# Proving $f(x,y) = y - x$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

How do you prove $f(x,y) = y - x$ is continuous?  The domain is $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ and the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$.  Is there an easy way to do it using the definition that the preimage of an open set is an open set?  I don't have much experience proving multivariable functions are continuous.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be continuous? When is $x/y/z$ undefined?

Comment: @Shahar I realize it is defined everywhere, but I still want to rigorously prove it is continuous using one of the equivalent characterizations of continuity.  Checking for the existence of points where it is undefined is not rigorous enough for me.

Comment: $g(x,y) = x$ is continuous for exactly the same reason that $a(x) = x$ is continuous ($y$ has no effect). Similarly, $h(x,y) = y$ is continuous. Therefore $f(x,y) = g(x,y) - h(x,y)$ is continuous.

Comment: @Bungo $a(x) = x$ is continuous because $a^{-1}(U)$ is open if $U$ is open (because $a^{-1}(U) = U$).  But how does this show $g^{-1}(U)$ is open if $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open?  $g^{-1}(U) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$ here, so we can't say $g^{-1}(U) = U$.

Comment: @user46944: I'm writing an answer now which will use the definition you indicated.

Comment: @Bungo Ok, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's prove it from the definition you stated.

Let $z$ be any point in $\mathbb{R}$, and let $(a,b)$ be any point such that $f(a,b) = z$. For example, $(a,b) = (0,z)$ is one such point.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Note that if $|x-a| < \epsilon/2$ and $|y-b| < \epsilon/2$, then
$$\begin{align}
|f(x,y) - f(a,b)| &= |(y-x) - (b - a)|\\
&= |(y-b) - (x-a)| \\
&\leq |y-b| + |x-a| \\
&< \epsilon\end{align}$$
This shows that $f$ maps the open square centered at $(a,b)$ with side lengths equal to $\epsilon$ into $B_\epsilon(z) \subset \mathbb{R}$, the $\epsilon$-neighborhood centered at $z$. Therefore the circle of radius $\epsilon/2$ centered at $(a,b)$ (namely $B_{\epsilon/2}(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$) is also mapped into $B_\epsilon(z)$.

To see this, it suffices to prove that if $\sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2} < \epsilon/2$, then $|x-a| < \epsilon/2$ and $|y-b| < \epsilon/2$.

But this is straightforward: 
$$\sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2} < \epsilon/2$$
implies
$$(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 < \epsilon^2/4$$
Since both $(x-a)^2$ and $(y-b)^2$ are nonnegative, this inequality forces both $(x-a)^2 < \epsilon^2/4$ and $(y-b)^2 < \epsilon^2/4$. Taking square roots gives us what we want.

Comment: I understand your proof, except now I want to rigorously show that the $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$-neighborhood around $(a,b)$ is contained in the open square centered at $(a,b)$ with the length of each side $\epsilon$.  Obviously, if we draw a picture, it makes sense.  I have a feeling we will be using the inequality in @Pelto's answer, though I'm not sure.

Comment: @user46944 - sure, I'll add that step

Comment: I think you meant $(x - a)^{2} + (y - b)^{2} < \frac{\epsilon^{2}}{4}$, but the idea makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: @user46944: Yes, good catch! I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 1):

Notice $|f(x,y)-f(x_o, y_o)| \leq |x-x_o|+|y-y_o| \leq 2 \sqrt{(x-x_o)^2+(y-y_o)^2}$.

You may workout the details of these weak inequalities if you would like.

Given $\epsilon>0$, define $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

This function is actually uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Is there a name for the inequality $|x - x_{0}| + |y - y_{0}| \leq 2 \sqrt{(x - x_{0})^{2} + (y - y_{0})^{2}}$?

Comment: @user46944 It follows from $\frac{x_1+\ldots+x_n}{n}\leqslant\sqrt{\frac{x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2}{n}}$ which is arithmetic vs. quadratic mean inequlity

Comment: I know it from the fact that the 'taxicab' metric is equivalent to the 'standard/Euclidean' metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given, and take $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

If $||(x,y)-(a,b)||<\delta$, then $\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\implies|x-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|y-b|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, so

$|f(x,y)-f(a,b)|=|(y-x)-(b-a)|=|(a-x)+(y-b)|\le|x-a|+|y-b|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

This proof does not use the "preimage of open set" technique, but the idea behind it might be useful going forward.

Given $X$ , $Y$ [metric spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ a function, we have the following [characterization of continuity](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Continuity/Metric_Space/Point):

> $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous if and only if for any sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset X$ so that $a_n \to a$, the limit of the sequence $\{f(a_n)\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ exists and is equal to $f(a)$.

With this in mind, take any convergent sequence $\{(x_n,y_n)\}_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset \mathbb R^2$. Such a sequence converges if and only if $x_n \to a$ and $y_n \to b$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb R$. Apply [standard results](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Combination_Theorem_for_Sequences/Sum_Rule) on sequences to conclude that $\{f(x_n,y_n)\}_{n \in \mathbb N} =\{x_n-y_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is a convergent sequence with limit $a-b$.

Answer (score 1):

More topological answer

Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}$. Next let $(a,b)$ be a point in $f^{-1}(U)$, so $f(a,b)=b-a \in U$. Since $U$ is open, there is $\delta>0$ so that $B(f(a,b),\delta)=(b-a-\delta, \: b-a+\delta)$ is contained in $U$ (definition of an open set). Hence we have $f^{-1}[(b-a-\delta, \: b-a+\delta)] \subset f^{-1}(U)$. Consider the two lines $y=b-a-\delta+x$ and $y=b-a+\delta-x$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$,   $\: $ $f^{-1}[(b-a-\delta,\: b-a+\delta)]$ will be the strip between but not containing these two lines. The point $(a,b)$ will be equidistant from these two lines, which are $\sqrt{2}\delta$ apart. Hence $ B ( ( a , b ), \delta / \sqrt{2})$ is contained in $f^{-1}(U)$. Thus there is an open ball around any point in $f^{-1}(U)$ which is contained in $f^{-1}(U)$.